# Dependency missing? java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I'm somewhat experienced in programming but pretty new to Maven. In my latest project I'm using the Apache Commons API (configuration, cli and so on). It compiles but throws me a NoSuchMethod-exception on runtime.

My dependencies look like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the method where the error occurs:

```
private Configuration parseConfig(String path) {
        File configFile = new File(path);
        if(!configFile.exists() || configFile.isDirectory()) {
            // Error config file path invalid
            CustomLogger.warn("ERROR file not found");
        }
        Configurations configs = new Configurations();
        Configuration config = null;
        try {
            config = configs.properties(configFile);
        }
        catch (ConfigurationException cex) {
            // Something went wrong
            CustomLogger.warn("Config Exception");
            cex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return config;
    }
```

The line/part/block where the error is happening exactly is:

```
try {
    config = configs.properties(configFile);
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.initBeanUtilsBean(BeanHelper.java:631)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.<clinit>(BeanHelper.java:89)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:294)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.fileBased(Parameters.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:602)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:614)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileBasedBuilder(Configurations.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.propertiesBuilder(Configurations.java:238)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.properties(Configurations.java:282)
        at com.core.utils.CustomConfiguration.parseConfig(CustomConfiguration.java:130)
```

What am I missing? There are several posts out there on Stack Overflow suggesting to include "commons-beanutils" in the dependencies. Doing so didn't change anything. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `File` class from `java.io` package, then the error is correct, there is no method or public member called "properties" - docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html .. 
If it should be some File class from bean utils (never seen :D), then is the problem maybe just in import?

Comment: make sure you run "mvn clean install" because it seems like you've messed up your dependencies and imports

Comment: I think it because of version incompatibility.

Comment: Appreciated your comments but nothing changed, it's likely a dependency conflict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a missing dependency.  It is an inconsistency between the dependencies at compile time and at runtime.

The problem is that the `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector` method was added between 1.8.3 and 1.9.0 of Apache Commons BeanUtils.

The POM dependencies say that you are compiling your code against 1.9.3, but the evidence is that your JVM is loading an older version at runtime.  Check your **runtime** classpath / WAR file / whatever to ensure that you have only one BeanUtils JAR, and that it is the correct version.

It is possible that there is an unnoticed conflict between your POM file's dependencies.  You can diagnose this by using the Maven Dependency Plugin to print out the dependency tree:

- https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-dependency-plugin-3.1.2/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: Seems like that's the case. How can I advise Maven to use a specific version over another?

Comment: Try this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management.  But first it is advisable to understand where the conflict came from ...

Answer (score 0):

I found very strange solution. My problem didn't go by updating project or clean build anything.

My project build on maven ,POM ,selenium testng.
I had made three class. Testbase"browser call n control", homePage"obj repo n methods" and testsclass" test scenarios n to call methods from Page classes". All worked fine but Now when i added one more test, i made loginpage"obj repo n methods for log in webpage" class. when i called LonginPage object repo from testclass it gave "Nosuchmethodsexception".

Solution: Removing `loginpage` constructor. Now I am able to call the method using `@Test` as a separate test to give priorities.

Note: I still have constructor in my `homePage` class.