# NoSuchMethodError? code is ok in idea, but wrong on cluster

Tags: apache-spark

My code runs okay on my win7 idea64, but when i package the code, and run it on yarn cluster, it throws an expection:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V
```

I checked the pom.xml, and find relative jars is already included

my `pom.xml` is like this:

```
<properties>
<scala.version>2.10.6</scala.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>cloudera</id>
    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The line/part/block where the error is happening exactly is:

```
line43  val config = ConfigurationUtil("config.properties").config
```

The stack trace is:

```
19/05/22 10:30:11 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1557905260816_0073_000002
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,yizheng
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,yizheng
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, yizheng); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, yizheng)
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization
19/05/22 10:30:12 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ... 
19/05/22 10:30:12 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.initBeanUtilsBean(BeanHelper.java:631)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.<clinit>(BeanHelper.java:89)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:307)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.properties(Parameters.java:246)
    at com.sunwada.utils.ConfigurationUtil$.<init>(ConfigurationUtil.scala:16)
    at com.sunwada.utils.ConfigurationUtil$.<clinit>(ConfigurationUtil.scala)
    at com.sunwada.sparkStreaming.SparkStreamKafkaHbaseSaveOffsetGson$.main(SparkStreamKafkaHbaseSaveOffsetGson.scala:43)
    at com.sunwada.sparkStreaming.SparkStreamKafkaHbaseSaveOffsetGson.main(SparkStreamKafkaHbaseSaveOffsetGson.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
19/05/22 10:30:13 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V)
19/05/22 10:30:22 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms. Please check earlier log output for errors. Failing the application.
19/05/22 10:30:22 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V)
19/05/22 10:30:22 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1557905260816_0073
19/05/22 10:30:23 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is the culprit.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

scope compile will be used for only compilation purpose.
you may need to change it to [runtime](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

OR
[It is an inconsistency between the dependencies at compile time and at runtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48745869/647053)

Comment: when change compile to runtime, it still doesn't work

Comment: when i add --driver-class-path /home/yizheng/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar --jars /home/yizheng/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar in my spark-submit shell  
under yarn client mode
the 'method not found error ' disappear, but program still not work, I want to cry

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError mostly caused by version conflict.you can install **dependency help plugin** in your IDE solve it

Comment: plugin is dependency analyzer